# I need help in 3UTools IPA signature

Tags: digital-signature, ipa

I want to sign an IPA file using 3UTools and my Apple ID, and I used to do it successfully every time. Now it says “Signature failed: unknown Mach format”
I tried to update 3UTools and iTunes, but the same problem happened.
Also, I tried to sign the IPA file using a local and working certificate but still the same thing.